# Create a new instance of an object, or modify the existing one?

Tags: c#, bittorrent

I'm attempting to create a BitTorrent library in C# as a side project, for fun. However, I've run into a design issue that could create problems later on if I don't address it now.

I currently have a `PeerGreeter` class, which puts a `Socket` in a listening state for any peers that try to connect to me, to serve me files in the torrent. When a peer connects, the greeter exchanges handshakes, makes sure everything is valid, and then fires a `PeerConnected` event with the associated `Socket` and handshake information as handler arguments.

My `Torrent` class, which is a representation of a single torrent and all its duties, has two lists of all peers in the swarm (encapsulated in a `Peer` object), connected and disconnected. When the greeter fires the `PeerConnected` event, the `Torrent` instance finds the corresponding `Peer` in the disconnected list. If it finds one, it moves it to the connected list, and sets a `Connection` property of type `Socket` in its instance to the `Socket` created by the greeter. The property is an auto-property with the access modifiers as: `{ get; internal set; }`

The problem I'm having is that this, as far as I know, isn't thread-safe. If one thread is working with a connection of a `Peer`, and then another thread modifies that connection object somehow, or disposes it, it could create issues. I've considered setting the `Connection` property's setter's access modifier to `private`, and having it set in the constructor, but the problem with that is that I need to create a new object to replace the placeholder `Peer` in the disconnected list to add it to the connected list.

My question is should I stick with having the setter as `internal`, or is making it `private` and replacing the placeholder with an entirely new instance a good approach as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For thread-safety purposes, making the type as immutable as possible will save you many, many headaches.  Make the accessor private (or better yet, mark the field as `readonly`) and generate new instances when changes need to be made.